# common plural noun

Tags: nouns, subject-verb-agreement, collective-nouns

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> The Italian was furious after the Turin giants were dumped out of the Champions League last season by a late Real Madrid penalty.

As I've been taught it should be incorrect because if we use 'the' before an adjective then that whole entity is a common plural noun, e.g. The French (French people), The poor (poor people) etc. so according to this logic we should use 'were' instead of 'was' with 'The Italian'. Am I right?

Comment: Downvoting for lack of the relevant context (once we have sight of the preceding paragraph, it's obvious that ***the Italian = Juventus chairman Andrea Agnelli***).

Answer (score 4):

You need more context to the quote:

> "The decision to bring forward its use follows lobbying from top clubs including Juventus, whose chairman, Andrea Agnelli, is also president of the powerful European Club Association (ECA), a union of the continent's biggest teams.
>
> The Italian was furious after the Turin giants were dumped out of the Champions League last season by a late Real Madrid penalty."

so "The Italian" is a reference to one person (Andrea Agnelli), not a nation and hence the grammar is correct

Comment: Note that although "French" does not modify in the plural, "Italian" does; if the quote was referring to all people in Italy, it would have said "the Italians".